# "Protect" text box value from input (HTML form)

Tags: html, forms, protected, assign

I was wondering whether it is possible to assign a value to an HTML text box and protect it.

What I mean is make it´s content unmodifiable, so that when the form gets submitted im "sure" it was this value which was submitted.

BTW I realize the easier way would be not to "listen" fot this input and just assign it but it would come in handy to be able to do what´s stated above.

I hope the question is clear enough, please ask for any needed clarification.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I was definitely not clear enough but I tried to express that i should hold the value after submitted (not modifiable in client side)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not.  You should never trust user input, which includes form submissions.

The other answers tell you how to mark the field as read-only.  This is useful if you want to display a particular value, while showing that it's not *intended* to edited.

However, it can still be modified with Firebug, DOM Inspector, etc.  Or, they can just submit a HTTP request without using the browser at all.

I would recommend storing the value in a session instead.

Comment: Ok so sessions is the way to go, javascript would be more of the asme such as all client side solution, am I correct?

Comment: I completely agree. If you don't want something edited, don't present it that way to the user.

Answer (score 7):

Set the `readonly` property of the input element:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

This will prevent any modification **(except if the user edits with a DOM Inspector). Always validate input on the server. If you do not want any changes made, don't allow the user to edit it.**

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Answer (score 3):

Form inputs have a 'disabled' and 'readonly' attributes you can set to make them un-editable.

http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/input.html

Though you can never be 100% sure what is getting sent from the client side.  The entire DOM is editable by the client.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this

```
<input type="text" value="VALUE" readonly />
```

Then itll be read only :)

Answer (score 3):

`<input type="text" readonly="readonly"/>`. But: **Never be sure, and validate data on the server side.** It is very easy to request GET/POST with invalid data.